# How to build a Buffer like overlay dialog as popup for Browser action?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just got started with chrome extensions and what I am trying to achieve is to display a overlay dialog (like how Buffer app does) instead of the regular popup. Any directions on how to would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: could you add a picture of what you are talking about?

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Comment: @ZakiullahKhanMohamed Buffer uses a bit of HTML, JavaScript, CSS and jQuery. Use the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) extension to view the source code of other extensions (in Buffer's case, look at `data/shared/buffer-overlay.js`).